# Problem with Debugging in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug the simple Hello World program that ships with Eclipse CDT. Running the program normally works fine, but when its run through debug mode, `puts()` doesn't print anything to the console.

I tried running the same program with gdb directly and it works fine, printing `"!!!Hello World!!!"` as expected.

Why doesn't `puts()` print anything when running in debug mode through Eclipse?

I'm on Windows with MinGW installed, running gcc 4.5.0, gdb 7.2, and CDT 7.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Swiss pointed out the right direction.
Adding `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf`,`puts` sentence is not suitable for a large project when **debugging** (When **releasing**, your'd better using `fflush()` at a appropriate time).
Then, we can use Preprocessor directives `#ifdef` && `setbuf()`.
In Eclipse , your C project -> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings :
 Confgiguration = "Debug [ Active ]" 
-> Tool Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> Symbols -> Add "_DEBUG",

Then in your main(), using:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
setbuf(stdout,NULL); // this disables buffering for stdout.
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to append \n in the puts statement? I.e. puts("Hello World!\n");
Some times terminal needs \n to flush the stream.

Comment: This didn't work, but it made me realize that the buffer might not be flushing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why this happens. When running GDB through a terminal, STDOUT is line buffered, which means that it will be flushed every time a newline is read, resulting in the behavior I was expecting.

HOWEVER! Eclipse CDT runs GDB with STDOUT in block buffered mode, which means it will only flush STDOUT when it reaches a certain size, or if it is manually flushed. Since the string "!!!Hello World!!!" is so short, the buffer for STDOUT will never be flushed unless a call to `fflush()` is made.

I managed to fix this problem by adding `fflush(stdout);` after the call to `puts()`.

Here's the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    fflush(stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```